# how to post json data and form data into single request in laravel 9

Tags: javascript, php, json, ajax, laravel-9

I have a form and inside the form I will possible input multiple image that i converted to put into json

**my form html** create.blade.php

```
<form method="post" action="{{ route('m_announcement.store') }}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                @csrf
/////// many input just not included 
//////// my image input
                 <div class="row mb-4">
                    <label class="col-sm-2 col-label-form">Upload Images</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                        <input type="file" name="files[]" id="files" multiple
                            accept="image/jpeg, image/png, image/gif," onchange="timeFunction()"><br />
                    </div>
                </div>

///////// my imagae preview
                <output id="Filelist"></output>

                <div class="text-center">
                    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Add" />
                </div>

</form>
```

This function in script output images to var AttachmentArray in json format that i want to post also with the form

```
        
        function printvalues() {
            console.log(AttachmentArray); all image converted in base64 output in json format with imahe details
```

is there is a way to join the json to the form and when i press submit the json and the data will output on request

**laravel 9 announcementcontroller.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
      
        //dd($request);
        $jsonimages = $request->jsonimages;

      // decode the json a create loop to upload to database image
      // some code to upload the form to announcement database

        //image upload
}
```

im not just into in frontend yet, most of this time im developing in backend first, this is my first web app project, im tried searching ajax or something but i dont understand that yet.

Answer (score 0):

you can get name of field input with

```
dd($request->file->('files'));
```

see here for more information [Retrieving files upload in laravel 9](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/requests#retrieving-uploaded-files)